# "knowledge is power" c language puzzle

Tags: c

what should be the output?
here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char *s[]={"knowledge","is","power"};
    char **p;
    p=s;
    printf("%s\n",++*p);
    printf("%s\n",*p++);
    printf("%s\n",++*p);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

**output:
nowledge
nowledge
s**

but here is the actual problem,
when I pre-increment ... the pointer jumps only 1 character (see the image below)
[image: click here to view 1st image]

but when I post-increment the pointer jumps the whole element
[image: click here to view 2nd image]

why are post and pre-increment working differently? according to me in both cases they should jump only 1 byte/character. i expected the output to be nowledge
nowledge
wledge 
(though i am wrong and output is nowledge nowledge s)

Comment: @Yunnosch that's for C++ .. try this link instead: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

Comment: @FelixPalmen Good point. Thanks for fixing the link to operator precedences of the wrong language.

Comment: please don't use images to post code - especially if the actual code you post is different from the one in the images. It's very confusing. Can you edit your question, and only include the code you are actually asking about ?

Comment: i think it might confuse the reader more as i wanted to associate different codes with different outputs. if i will mention 2-3 different codes and 2-3 outputs it might make it more confusing. i am basically trying not to confuse the readers with unnecessary test codes and outputs. i used test codes to define how i looked at the question and why i found it different.
i just did that to not confuse readers with different code and outputs mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

While "*operator precedence*" is important (although technically, C doesn't have any precedences but uses a grammar of allowed expressions instead, but you can [deduce a precedence table from that grammar](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence)) and explains how `*p++` increments `p` -- it isn't the *only* issue here.

With an expression like

```
++*p
```

it's simply the order of unary operators that matters. With these, you have to go from right to left to find the result. So, `p` is first dereferenced, the result (which is in your case a pointer to the first string) is then incremented by one.

To get `p` incremented instead, you just have to change the places of the operators:

```
*++p
```

This first increments and then dereferences.

Comment: i found this statement helpful:
"When parsing an expression, an operator which is listed on some row will be bound tighter (as if by parentheses) to its arguments than any operator that is listed on a row further below it. For example, the expression *p++ is parsed as *(p++), and not as (*p)++.  "
i saw it from the link you mentioned.

Comment: @Kandy that's the part about *precedence* -- but it doesn't explain the "pre-increment case".

Answer (score 1):

In the first case ++*p, evaluation takes place as ++(*p) - so the output will be modified in *p( `p` points to `knowledge`. When ++*p is done it becomes `nowledge`) 
In the second case *p++, evaluation takes place as *(p++) - In this case the pointing location is itself changed.

Answer (score 0):

The increments are not working differently. They're just working on different pointers due to [operator precedence and associativity](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

Specifically :

```
printf("%s\n",++*p);
```

`++*p` is the same as `++(*p)` : `*p` is the first item in the `s` array, which is a pointer to `"knowledge"`. Then the `++` increments that pointer by one, so it points to "nowledge".

```
printf("%s\n",*p++);
```

`*p++` is the same as `*(p++)` : `p++` makes `p` point to the second item of the `s` array, which is a pointer to `"is"`. But this happens only *after* the pointer is dereferenced using `*` (it is a *post*-increment after all). So, first, `"nowledge"` is printed again (because the first pointer in the `s` array was modified in the first step), and then `p` moves to the second item, `"is"`.

```
printf("%s\n",++*p);
```

This is again the same as the first step (but this time for the second item in the `s` array), so `"s"` is printed.

Comment: can you please explain in detail? how is the precedence effecting? I need a detailed answer as I don't know how is it actually affecting the output.

Comment: thanks. i got this. i was stuck. i was out of touch with c language since a year or two.

Answer (score 0):

That is the common confusion about the pre increment and post increment operators, order of evaluation and their precedence

`*++p` -----> `*(++p)` increments the pointer `p`, then dereferences

`++*p` -----> `++(*p)` dereferences first, then increments the dereferenced object

`*p++` -----> `*(p++)` dereferences first, then increments the pointer `p`

`(*p)++` -----> `(*p)++` dereferences first, then increments the dereferenced object

If you struggle with it, just use parentheses to explicit show the compiler what has to be evaluated and in what order.